# image creating slow down servre

Tags: php, gd, ram, uiimagejpegrepresentation

I have function and with this funqction I`m trying to create some images in my server

```
           foreach($value[0] as $imagekey => $imageval) {
                $imgname = $gancxadeba . '_' . $imagekey;
                $saveaddr = dirname(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])).'/www/classifieds_images/';
                $as = '.JPG';
                $originalname = $imgname . $as;
                if(!file_exists($saveaddr.$originalname)) {
                    if (preg_match('/\.(jpg)$/', $imageval)) {
                        $getfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageval);
                    } elseif (preg_match('/\.(JPG)$/', $imageval)) {
                        $getfile = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageval);
                    } elseif (preg_match('/\.(png)$/', $imageval)) {
                        $getfile = imagecreatefrompng($imageval);
                    } else {
                        $getfile = imagecreatefromgif($imageval);
                    }
                    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($imageval);
                    $newWidth = 90;
                    $newHeight = 120;
                    $original = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
                    imagecopyresampled($original, $getfile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
                    imagejpeg($original, "../www/classifieds_images/$originalname");
                    echo 'განცხადება: ' . $gancxadeba . ' ორიგინალი სურათი: ' . $imgname . ' created!' . PHP_EOL;

                    $thumbname = $imgname . '_THUMB' . $as;
                    if (!file_exists($saveaddr . $thumbname)) {
                        $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($newWidth, $newHeight);
                        imagecopyresampled($thumb, $getfile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $newWidth, $newHeight, $width, $height);
                        imagejpeg($thumb, "../www/classifieds_images/$thumbname");
                        echo 'განცხადება: ' . $gancxadeba . ' თამბი სურათი: ' . $imgname . ' created!' . PHP_EOL;
                    }
                }
                $image[$imagekey] = $imgname;
            }
```

as you understand I`m getting image link and then chacking if file exists and I`m creating file if it not exists.
but my server slow down.
it is using 2GB RAM.
what can I do to accelerate my server?

I tryed file_put_content() first and then creating thumb
but it not working as well as gd library.
so please help me to do this function quicker than is.

Comment: It's not creating a file that slow down. But using Image Library, have you tried the most famous ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing to note (not really an answer to your problem):
When using GD2 functions, don't trust file extension. Someone could save JPEG with name "trollpic.gif" and cause your imagecreatefromgif to throw an error.

Use exif data instead:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php

Also - you could try imegemagick as an alternative to GD2 if that's possible (it's not on some cheaper hosting services).

[EDIT]

```
$original = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopyresampled($original, $getfile, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($original, "../www/classifieds_images/$originalname");
```

Looks like $getfile and $original both keep the same data.
Check if this will work:

```
$original = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagejpeg($getfile, "../www/classifieds_images/$originalname");
```

It's not the best you can do to optimize your code, but at least it's a start.
I'd recommend setting some limit to how many files can be processed in one execution of the script and queueing it - that's the best you could do if you're trying to process a lot of data, not necessarily image related.

[EDIT2]

Also - unset variables when they're no longer needed.
When you've done everything to an image and saved it in a file - destroy the resource. It won't remove image file, just drop its data from memory.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php

Comment: yes. it is now quicker than was. but it is using 2GB RAM . what can I do to minimize using RAM?